# Google Chart visualization not working in google earth popup

Tags: google-visualization, google-earth

I have javascript code for a Google Chart Visualiation within the Description tag for a popup balloon in a kml file.  The chart displays fine in a browser but not in Google Earth.  The kml file opens in Google Earth but the popup is displayed without the chart, which is missing in the display.  I can't figure out why this is not working.

Here's how it looks in Google Earth: [Google Earth Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9zbC.png)

Example code:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' xmlns:gx='http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2'
xmlns:kml='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
<Document>
<name>Chart Test</name>
<Placemark id='ABBEY'>
<Snippet maxLines='0'></Snippet>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<head>
<style type=text/css>
p {text-align:left; font-family:'Comic Sans MS'; font-size:10pt; line-height:120%; padding:0pt; margin-top:0pt;}
.center {text-align:center;}
.space {margin-top:6pt;}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
 ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
 ['Work',     11],
 ['Eat',      2],
 ['Commute',  2],
 ['Watch TV', 2],
 ['Sleep',    7]
]);
var options = {
title: 'My Daily Activities',
is3D: true,
};
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>
<div style='height:300px; width:350px; overflow:auto'>
<body>
<table colspan='1'>
<tr>
<td colspan='1' align='center'>
<h2 align='center'>Chart Test</h2>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='1' align='center'>
<h2>ABBEY</h2>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='1' align='center'>
<div id='piechart_3d' style='width: 150px; height: 150px;'></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='1' align='center'>
<h3 class='center'>Chart should appear in space above</h3>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</div>
]]>
</description>
<Point>
<coordinates>-73.059764,44.03325</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

This question was asked previously but no answers were posted:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936891/google-chart-api-not-working-inside-kml-balloon

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Earth strips out any javascript in a Balloon description for security purposes. A common workaround is to listen for a click event on your placemark (or a balloonopening event more generally) and then recreate an HtmlDivBalloon programmatically with the full content. For more details check out http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/balloons.html#getballoonhtmlunsafe

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the link you posted does not help.  It just takes me to a page that says the Google Earth API is no longer available.  In the past, I've used the Google Chart API that uses a URL string to create the chart, but my understanding is that is being phased out so I need to learn to use the javascript version.  However, I'm too much of a novice to really understand how to listen for a click event on the placemark and then create the balloon programatically.  If you have any other sources of more detailed information on this I'd be most grateful.